# Properties of the Cantor set constructed by removing just the middle point

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set, fractal-analysis

**Context:**

I am currently doing some exercises on the middle $\lambda$ Cantor set $C_\lambda$ (construction is similar to the usual Cantor set, but we remove the middle $\lambda$ proportion of the intervals). One involves showing that the Hausdorff dimension function mapping the set of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,1]$, namely, $\dim_H(.):\mathcal{K}\to[0,1]$ is not continuous. I was thinking of construction a sequence $k_n:=C_{\frac{1}{n}}$. I still need to show this converges to $C_0$ which I'm going to define as the Cantor set constructed by removing the middle point.

**Question:**

Anyways, I believe that sketch of a proof should work, but I'm curious as to the properties of $C_0$. Would its dimension be $1$ Since the Hausdorff dimension is invariant of countable points? What is its measure? What type of numbers are left in the limiting set of this particular construction? Is there anything 'interesting' about this set compared to the usual $C_\lambda$?

EDIT (construction):

I assume the $C_\lambda$ construction isn't the issue, so I will omit that.

$$(C_{0})_0=[0,1]$$
$$(C_{0})_1=[0,1/2)\cup{}(1/2,1]$$
$$(C_{0})_2=[0,1/4)\cup{}(1/4,1/2)\cup{}(1/2,3/4)\cup{}(3/4,1]$$
$$C_0:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}{(C_{0})_n}$$

I am asking about the properties of $C_0$ as defined above. However, as a side question, Is this the limiting set of $k_n$, or would that just be [0,1]?

Comment: Normally $C_\lambda$ is constructed by removing an _open_ interval at each stage. But by this definition, $C_0$ is simply $[0,1]$. Did you intend to use a different definition for this special case? Please clarify!

Comment: Please write out the first stages of your construction.

Comment: You're removing all the *dyadic rationals*, the numbers $p/q$ with $q$ a power of two. What's left has full measure. It consists of all the numbers whose base two expansion doesn't terminate.

Comment: What do you mean by the _limiting set_ of $k_n$? Do you mean the set of all $x\in[0,1]$ such that $x\in k_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$? That set is just $\{0,1\}$, isn't it? (Not $[0,1]$!)

Comment: Any thoughts on my comment, kam?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry for the delay, thank you, that was very helpful.